# AppLocalizations missing reference - Internationalization - Flutter

Tags: flutter

flutter_gen applocalizations missing reference in Visual Studio Code.

[image]

I already tried

- flutter upgrade
- flutter pub cache clean
- flutter clean / flutter pub get
- Dart: Restart Analysis Server (VS Code)
- Developer: Reload Window (VS Code)

My pubspec.yaml has

- generate: true
- flutter_localizations:sdk: flutter

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- My machine was with 2 `flutter sdk` installed. I unnistalled one, and everything worked again.